# Bootstrap not working good with MOBILE version

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem: My PC view of the website works correctly, but the Android version not.

**PC view:** http://www.boosting99.com

[image: screenshot]

**Picture of Android version:**

[image: Android]

Comment: It's not Bootstrap's default settings. You need to setup the behaviour of icons on narrow screen.

Comment: Is it hard to do it? How can I do it?

Comment: I think you need to decide how it should look in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? :

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h6>"your support email"</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h6>"your icons goes here</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

and you can use `media-left` for your icons.

Reference : [getbootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)